# For which $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in[1,\infty]$ is $u \in W^{k,p}(B_1(0))$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u: \overline B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$u(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2(1-\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})$$
For  which $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ p \in[1,\infty] $ is $ u \in W^{k,p}(B_1(0)) $ ? 
I  don't  have any  clue. Thanks  for  helping !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Your question will be easier to read (and write) if you only encase the _math_ in dollar signs, not your entire question.

Comment: "I don't have any clue" is a pretty strong statement. Do you know what $W^{k,p}(B_1(0))$ is?

Comment: Yes , the Sobolev space . I think I have to compute the partial derivatives and look if they are in L^p

Comment: Yes. In fact $x_1x_2$ is (obviously?) in every Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(B_1(0))$ so you can just consider $x_1x_2 \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$.  Start calculating.

Comment: My difficulty is that I have to take all partial derivatives and look if these are in L^p . My clue was that every times I compute a partial derivative I get $$ (\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})^{(\frac{2\alpha-1}2)} $$  if the order is $  \alpha $  and this I can estimate using polar coordinates  . $$        x_1=r*cos(\phi) \ x_2=r*sin(\phi)   . $$

Comment: Good evening . I think I have to show that . $$  \int_{B_1(0)}|D^{\alpha}(x_1,x_2)|^p<\infty  $$ , but I do not know how to compute it .

Comment: Now I found out that  $$  x_1x_2\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\in W^{k,p}(B_1(0))  $$ , is it correct  ?